# Android SQLite - table "..." has no column named "..."

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am getting the listed error and have looked through and through the code and am either missing what's wrong or there is nothing wrong and the code is just being a jerk, but here is my database handler class.. I have tried updating the database version number, uninstalling the app, but neither have seemed to work. Thanks

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "loginManager";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "loginTable";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String KEY_QUESTION = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT"
                + KEY_QUESTION + " TEXT"
                + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, contact.getPassword());
        values.put(KEY_QUESTION, contact.getQuestion());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, contact.getAnswer());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single contact
    Contact getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_PASSWORD, KEY_QUESTION, KEY_ANSWER }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPassword(cursor.getString(2));
                contact.setQuestion(cursor.getString(3));
                contact.setAnswer(cursor.getString(4));

                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, contact.getPassword());
        values.put(KEY_QUESTION, contact.getQuestion());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, contact.getAnswer());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

& The Contact class

```
public class Contact {

    //private variables
        int _id;
        String _name;
        String _password;
        String _question;
        String _answer;

        // Empty constructor
        public Contact(){

        }
        // constructor
        public Contact(int id, String name, String password, String question, String answer){
            this._id = id;
            this._name = name;
            this._password = password;
            this._question = question;
            this._answer = answer;
        }

        // constructor
        public Contact(String name, String password, String question, String answer){
            this._name = name;
            this._password = password;
            this._question = question;
            this._answer = answer;
        }
        // getting ID
        public int getID(){
            return this._id;
        }

        // setting id
        public void setID(int id){
            this._id = id;
        }

        // getting name
        public String getName(){
            return this._name;
        }

        // setting name
        public void setName(String name){
            this._name = name;
        }

        public String getPassword(){
            return this._password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password){
            this._password = password;
        }

        public String getQuestion(){
            return this._question;
        }

        public void setQuestion(String question){
            this._question = question;
        }

        public String getAnswer(){
            return this._answer;
        }

        public void setAnswer(String answer){
            this._answer = answer;
        }

}
```

LogCat

```
11-07 12:30:55.151: E/SQLiteLog(32200): (1) table loginTable has no column named answer
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200): Error inserting answer=answer question=question password=pass name=name
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table loginTable has no column named answer (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO loginTable(answer,question,password,name) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1118)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:691)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1589)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1461)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at com.example.duradoornfc.DatabaseHandler.addContact(DatabaseHandler.java:72)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at com.example.duradoornfc.CreateUserActivity.addUser(CreateUserActivity.java:135)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at com.example.duradoornfc.CreateUserActivity.action_Click(CreateUserActivity.java:91)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3833)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
11-07 12:30:55.161: E/SQLiteDatabase(32200):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your logcat please

Comment: Logcat has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing some comas on your create statement:

```
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_QUESTION + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Remember to change your database version after you change it's structure.